# procedure under SYSTEM is invalid

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a successfully compiled procedure under SYSTEM schema.

```
create or replace procedure get_file_list as

    ns      varchar2(1024);
    cursor c_my_directory is
        select directory_name, directory_path from all_directories where directory_path like '/home/oracle/EDI%';
begin

    -- before generating the file list, the temporary table is deleted
    delete from edi.temp_EDI_file_list;

    for each_directory in c_my_directory loop
        -- it reads the contents of my_directory into a table called X$FRBMSFT
        sys.dbms_backup_restore.searchfiles (each_directory.directory_path, ns);

        for each_file in (select fname_krbmsft as name from X$KRBMSFT) loop
            insert into edi.temp_edi_file_list
            values (each_directory.directory_name, each_file.name);
        end loop;
    end loop;

    commit;

    exception
        when others then 
            raise_application_error (-20001,sqlcode || ' ' || sqlerrm);

end get_file_list;
```

[.. it was created under SYSTEM schema because I am not allowed to grant select on X$FRBMSFT to user "edi"].

I granted execute privilegies to user "edi" on this procedure.
[.. connected as SYSTEM, role SYSDBA, I executed `grant execute on system.get_file_list to EDI;`]

When I am trying to execute the procedure (`execute system.get_file_list;`) with user "edi" it return the error

> PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.GET_FILE_LIST is invalid

Can someone, please, give me a hint about what am I doing wrong?

Thank you,

Comment: It successfully compiled - without any errors reported? What does the `user_errors` view show for that procedure (when connected as system)? Does system have permission to see edi's table, with directly granted privileges - not via a role? (Not sure why you can't grant privs to edi instead of creating this in the system schema, which - as you seem to be aware - should be avoided.)

Comment: Why are you creating a procedure under system schema? Avoid it.

Comment: @KaushikNayak: I mentioned in my post the reason why I created the procedure under SYSTEM schema. Do you have other idea to let me interogate X$KRBMSFT table?

Comment: That's a really strange DBA who prefers to create procedures in the SYSTEM schema, over granting access to an internal system view

Comment: @AlexPoole: 
-- the compilation is successfully, with no errors.
-- checking `user_error` view under SYSTEM schema returns no errors.
-- yes, SYSTEM have SELECT, DELETE, INSERT privs on EDI (grant select, delete, insert on edi.temp_edi_file_list to system;)
-- I tried to grant select on X$KRBMSFT table to EDI (grant select on X$KRBMSFT to EDI;) but it gave me the error `ORA-02030: can only select from fixed tables/views`

Comment: So this code is the first code Dan Morgan posted on his [Morgan's Library site](https://www.morganslibrary.org/hci/hci002.html). Why not implement the safer solution he provides later in the article?

Comment: @APC: the link cannot be reached. Can you post here the solution, please?

Comment: The link is fine. Why do you say it *"cannot be reached"*?

Comment: Also: can you execute the procedure when connected as SYSTEM?

Comment: @APC: I tried the solution from the linked you proposed (I finally managed to open it). As SYSTEM, the procedure is successfully executed but as EDI, it returns me the error `PLS-00905: object SYSTEM.GET_FILE_LIST is invalid`

Comment: ...but when I am looking into user_objects, it shows me that it is valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186788/discussion-between-mikcutu-and-apc).

Comment: Sorry I can't do chat at the moment

Answer (score 1):

In the end I managed to create the procedure, with some help from the [link](https://www.morganslibrary.org/hci/hci002.html) provided by @APC.

... conected as SYSTEM

```
create or replace view file_list as select fname_krbmsft from X$KRBMSFT readonly;

create or replace procedure searchfiles (pattern in out nocopy varchar2, ns in out nocopy varchar2) authid definer as
begin
    dbms_backup_restore.searchfiles(pattern, ns);
end searchfiles;

GRANT SELECT ON FILE_LIST TO EDI;
GRANT EXECUTE ON SEARCHFILES TO EDI;
```

... conected as EDI

```
create or replace procedure get_file_list as

    ns      varchar2(1024);
    cursor c_my_directory is
        select directory_name, directory_path from all_directories where directory_path like '/home/oracle/EDI%';
begin

    -- before generating the file list, the temporary table is deleted
    delete from edi.temp_EDI_file_list;

    for each_directory in c_my_directory loop
        -- it reads the contents of all directories into a table called X$FRBMSFT via procedure SEARCHFILES
        sys.SEARCHFILES (each_directory.directory_path, ns);

        -- it interogate the X$FRBMSFT via file_list view
        for each_file in (select fname_krbmsft as name from sys.file_list) loop
            insert into temp_edi_file_list
            values (each_directory.directory_name, each_file.name);
        end loop;
    end loop;

    commit;

    exception
        when others then 
            raise_application_error (-20001,sqlcode || ' ' || sqlerrm);

end get_file_list;
```

The difference was made by the way they were called the objects created with user SYSTEM. They were called with SYS.xxx instead of SYSTEM.xxx